# Unable to add subviews to a UIView when using the View's layer as a mask

Tags: ios, uiview, core-animation, calayer

I am trying to animate a UIView with a popover kind of effect, and I want the background of the UIView to have that ios7 style blur as the background.

Making this slightly more complicated, I'd also like to be able to apply a transform to the popover and its contents by dragging the corner, much like a chat in the Facebook app.

Now, my approach is basically this: take a blurred snapshot of the window, add a UIImageView as a subview of the controller's view, mask that imageView with the UIView popover. However, I am then finding that I can not interact with that UIView at all - subviews don't show up, gesture recognizers don't fire, etc.

Here is my code:

```
UIWindow *mainWindow = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
CGRect frame = [self.tableView.tableHeaderView convertRect:self.displayView.frame toView:self.view];

UIView *view = [UIView new];
view.frame = frame;
view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
view.layer.cornerRadius = 10.f;
view.tag = 100;

//Take the snapshot
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(mainWindow.rootViewController.view.bounds.size, YES, [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]);
[mainWindow drawViewHierarchyInRect:mainWindow.bounds afterScreenUpdates:NO];
UIImage *screenImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
UIImage *blur = [screenImage applyDarkEffect];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:blur];
imageView.frame = self.view.bounds;

[self.view addSubview:imageView];
[self.view addSubview:view];

imageView.layer.mask = view.layer;

//Animate the view
    [UIView animateKeyframesWithDuration:1.4f delay:0.0f options:UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptionCalculationModeCubic
                              animations:^{
                                  [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:0.0 relativeDuration:0.75 animations:^{
                                      view.frame = CGRectInset(mainWindow.frame, 30, 40);
                                  }];
                                  [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:0.75 relativeDuration:0.05 animations:^{
                                      view.frame = CGRectInset(mainWindow.frame, 20, 30);
                                  }];
                                  [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:0.8 relativeDuration:0.20 animations:^{
                                      view.frame = CGRectInset(mainWindow.frame, 25, 35);
                                  }];
                              } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                                  //This does nothing.
                                  UIView *test = [UIView new];
                                  test.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100);
                                  test.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
                                  [view addSubview:test];
                              }];
```

Any insights in to why this isn't working? Or alternative approaches?

One alternate approach I thought of would be to roll my own keyframe animation: Add the imageView as a subview of the 'view', use an update timer, and calculate the frame of the view for each frame, offsetting the image view appropriately. But I was hoping there would be an easier way around this issue.

Comment: If gesture recognizers aren't firing and subviews aren't showing up then I would double check your frames. An easy way to do this is to add a border to the layer. Here is a handy macro that I often use `#define HIGHLIGHT_VIEW(v, color) [[v layer] setBorderWidth:1.0f]; [[v layer] setBorderColor:[color CGColor]];`

Comment: Ya i've checked and double checked this -- if I comment out the imageView.layer.mask = view.layer everything works as expected.